# How to get numerical value from String containing digits and characters

Tags: javascript

Is there any built in method to get which can parse int from string ("23px")?

I know I can use `substring` and then `parseInt` but I want to know if there is any other way available to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`parseInt` will grab the first set of contiguous numbers:

```
parseInt('23px');
```

returns 23.

If there is any chance there will be leading zeros, use a radix:

```
parseInt('23px', 10);
```

which is a good habit in general.

Answer (score 3):

parseInt can do it. Just use:

```
var num = parseInt("23px", 10);
```

It will parse the integer part and ignore the rest.